# Word file Error

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, storage

I was working on a Word file in office and copied the file to a USB memory to continue editing on my house's computer.
When I opened the file I found that the Last Modified date was 26/2/2015 but, When I opened the file, The data in it was old as I modified it days ago.

So, The last modified data is 26/2/2015 but, the data in the file was modified earlier.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You have not asked a question, rather made a statement. Please **[edit]** your question to include specific details about what you are trying to accomplish and what you have attempted. Additional information about **[ask]** is available in the [help].

Comment: Someone understood it and replied, Should I still change the question?

Comment: For the sake of improving the question to be complete and accurate, yes, you should still update the question. You can then request it be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

The last modified date of a file changes when you copy it, because the copy of the file, was last modified on the date that you copied it. That's why it shows like the **new** file was copied. You might want to try saving the Word file on the previous computer again and make sure that you copy the file corrently.

Windows Explorer causes this to happen, so if you want to keep the original modified date you need to use `xcopy` in a terminal with the `/K` flag.